# XSLT: Check if String A contains any element of a tokenized String B

Tags: xslt

I have a delimited string `source`, and I want to know if any of its tokenized substrings are in `target` (which can also be tokenized). Does the XSLT function [filter](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/filter.html) provide this result?

```xsl
<xsl:variable name="source">2.0;2.1;2.2;2.3</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="target">2.2;3.0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="source_tokenized">
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($source,';')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="filter($source_tokenized ,contains($target,.))"/>
```

In this example, `2.2` is contained in `2.2;3.0`, so in this case one of the source's tokens is indeed contained in the target.

My syntax is incorrect, as I get a message

```
static error near {...versions ,contains($target,...} in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 368 column 83 of stylesheet.xsl:
  XPST0017: Cannot find a 2-argument function named
  Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}filter(). Higher-order functions are not
  available in this Configuration
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

- Is `filter` the function for this job? If so, how do I use it?
- If not, what is a better approach? (General advice needed, not actual code.)

Comment: If you want to know if the value of `target` is equal to one of the tokens contained in `source`, you can simply test for `$target = tokenize($source, ';')`.

Comment: I updated my post based on your response. There are scenarios in which `target` is not one of the `source`'s tokens.

Comment: The error message suggests that you're using an old-ish version of Saxon-HE; recent versions include support for higher order functions from the XSLT 3.0 specification. Having said that, using filter() is not the right approach in this case, and you're using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if any of its tokenized substrings are in target

This expression:

```
tokenize($target, ';') = tokenize($source, ';')
```

will return `true()` if there is at least one token in `$target` that is equal to any token in `$source`. Otherwise it will return `false()`.

Comment: Love it. Thank you.